# Debug CakePhp Step by step

Tags: cakephp

My client want the code I've did in a subfolder.
I've put everything inside but I have only a blank page.

When I try to use phpinfo in the index file, nothing appears.
On the app/core.php the same

I don't have access to root to test if it's an issue with the root .htaccess or with my script.

Which cakephp file should be called first if the subdomain setup is good?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

> Ok I know what's wrong. SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3 does not work on the shared
>   hosting where my client have his main website. The client does not
>   want to upgrade the php version and this directive in the .htaccess
>   seems to be ignored. What alternatives do I have ...?

Comment: try by setting Configure::write('debug', 2); in core.php

Comment: and need more specific question, I've put everything inside means?

Comment: I mean the whole project I had on my dev root, in his subfolder.

Comment: I have nothing shown with debug 2 :(

Comment: remove the htaccess file and check any test page

Comment: Ok I know what's wrong. SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3 does not work on the shared hosting where my client have his main website. The client does not want to upgrade the php version and this directive in the .htaccess seems to be ignored. What alternatives do I have ...?

Comment: add your this point in main question